# How to use webpack components

Tags: node.js, webpack

Due to the lack of support of modules or packages under development in npm I have decided to use webpack's components which from the look of the example provided here [webpack/examples/components](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/component) seems to be exactly what I am looking for. However there is no example how to actually use the example. Drawing from webpack's convention I thought that:

```
webpack/examples/components> webpack component.json > bundle.js
```

would do the trick but nope I get an error. Tried some other stuff like putting an entry file and an output file in the webpack.config.js but no luck there either. Has someone ever use it, does it work and most importantly how to start it?

Comment: What error do you get? Try to provide as much info as possible with issues. Also, are you aware that `component` is no longer being maintained? https://github.com/componentjs/component/issues/639

Comment: that example is meh.  also it looks like component is meh. so you save your self some webpack heartache and try another solution. =)